# Cart quantity on header shared component is not updating from another component in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular10

I would like the no. of items on cart icon which is on header component to be increase when I click on 'Add to cart' button. But the same is working only when I refresh the page.

I am using cart service to store global data and then access the same on header component. I did subcribe the Subject behaviour On init. Please have a look at these code snippets:

My cart.service.ts file:

```
export class CartService {
  public cartItem: ICartItem[] = [];
  cartItems = new BehaviorSubject<ICartItem[]>(this.cartItem);
  cartItems$ = this.cartItems.asObservable();

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.GetCartData()
  }

  GetCartData() {
    if (this.cookieService.check('cartItems')) {
      this.cartItem = JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('cartItems'));
    } else {
      this.cartItem = [];
    }
    this.cartItems.next(this.cartItem);
  }

  publishCartChange() {
    this.cartItem = JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('cartItems'));
    this.cartItems.next(this.cartItem);
  }

  AddCartItem(item: ICartItem) {
    this.cartItem.push(item);
    this.cookieService.set('cartItems', JSON.stringify(this.cartItem));
    this.cartItems.next(this.cartItem);
  }
}
```

How I am accessing it on header component:

```
this.cartService.publishCartChange();
    this.cartItemSub = this.cartService.cartItems$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.cartItems = res;
      console.log(res);
      this.cartQty = this.cartItems.length;
    });
```

This is what my 'Add to cart' button do:

```
addtoCart() {
    let cartItem: ICartItem = {'ItemId': this.product['itemId'], 'ItemName': this.product['itemName'], price: this.product['specialPrice'], 'qty': this.qty, 'amount': this.product['specialPrice']* this.qty };
    this.cartService.AddCartItem(cartItem);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add an injectable attribute, and specify that it be registered with the root injector? This will make it an application-wide singleton, which is likely what you want.

Make sure to remove it from the `providers` array from any NgModule/Component, if you've registered it via the module/component.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CartService {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I was knowing this but it was showing me result on refresh so I was less bothered to it.